# cakePHP 3.3 cast typeMap in where()

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, orm

I'm trying to get data from a table field customernumber of type `VARCHAR`. This is the case, because the customernumbers can be like "0024" and "1234".

The `$query->getTypeMap()` tells me that it has type `string` in cakePHP.  Now our customer wants to get the customer with "0024", when typing "24" or "0024".

No problem I thought to myself, so that I just have typcast the input value to `int`. But the cakePHP ORM seems to cast according to the typemap and I have no clue how to change the type on the fly.

I tried:

```
$query->find()
      ->select()
      ->where(['customernumber' => intval($input)]
      ->typeMap(['customernumber' => 'integer']);
```

but I recieve an empty result, when typing 24 in my search input.

I hope you see what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: can't you just use mysql CAST?

Comment: Mhh, you mean something like this: `$query->find()->select()->where(['customernumber' => $query->func()->cast($input)]->typeMap(['customernumber' => 'integer']); ` ? Sadly I won't recieve a result either.

Comment: no `where([$query->func()->cast('customernumber') => $input]) ` or something like it (I did not actually tried that code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone and sorry if I wasn't that clear in my question, but this morning I was able to find a solution, after taking in account your comments and answer and debugging a bit through the ORM I finally found a solution, which is working for me.

The problem was that the field customernumber was set to type "text" and when doing a compare operation like `customernumber = :comparevalue`, the `:comparevalue` was always cast to a text. So I had to map it to 'Integer' on the fly, which I'm doing like that now:

```
$query->where(function ($exp) use ($input) {
    return $exp->eq('customernumber', intval($input), 'integer');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use mysql CAST function

```
    $cast = $query->func()->convert([
            'customernumber' => 'identifier',
            'signed' => 'literal'
        ]) ;

    $input = '0024';

    $query
        ->where(function ($exp) use ($cast, $input) {
        return $exp->eq($cast, intval($input));
    });
```

in this way the generated query would be

```
WHERE (convert((username), signed)) = '23'
```

Comment: Thank you, it will generate the where query part as you have pointed out, but I still get no results. I also tried to query the database directly in MySQL Workbench but will also get no results. I don't know, but is it possible to cast a table field that way in a where clause ...

Comment: @ndm: the problem with your idea is, that our customer had not standardized its customernumbers in the past, so it might be, that there are numbers like "0042", but also some like "01234". :/

Comment: @Seb I see, from your question it appeared as if there was a 4 char limit.